# Add text view and image view desirable place

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uitextview

I have create an iPhone quiz application .Some of the questions have question image and some have only text. I have take a text view for displaying question and an image view for displaying question image . But problem is that when small sized question is appear then there have big gap between question and image. But i want to set same distance for all sized questions. How can i do that. please help me to solve this .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the NSString method `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` to get the height of your text, and then just add that on to the y value of the image/text.